# Parsing json data with nested array in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, jsonp, json.net

I have gone through many references. But i didn't get the idea to how to parse the json data with nested array.

```
{
"data": [{
    "location": {
        "id": "833",
        "latitude": 37.77956816727314,
        "longitude": -122.41387367248539,
        "name": "Civic Center BART"
    },
"likes": {
        "count": 190,
        "data": [{
            "username": "shayne",
            "full_name": "Shayne Sweeney",
            "id": "20",
            "profile_picture": "..."
        }, {...subset of likers...}]
    },
```

with the use of JObject i can parse the data. But getting values of data objects which is inside 'like' using for loop is not working.

```
var newsfeeds = from f in jsonObject["data"].Children()
                            select new Feeds
                            {
                                Name = (string)f["name"],
                                ID = (string)f["id"],
                                Link = (string)f["link"],
                                Message = (string)f["story"],
                                Picture = (string)f["picture"],
                                Created_time = (string)f["created_time"],
                                likes =  ?
                                };
```

Here is the problem occur in question mark. likes is an list of likes object. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you put the full json please ?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match up with the JSON data you posted.  Is there more to it?  Also, what data are you trying to get from "likes"?  It's not very clear what you're really trying to do here.

Comment: Json data which I have is a big one. you can see that in this link http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/ . Check the feed response of instagram. I feel difficult to parse comments and likes. @Brian Rogers - if youn see that json in that link, you can get idea. I could't post it as it is a big one. Thanks for your reply

Comment: The JSON you linked to in the documentation doesn't parse.  Can you post the JSON that you actually receive back from the web service when you call it?  If it is "too big" then dump it onto [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and link to that.